Override -- operator in C#
I try to overide -- operator.
I want prefix and postfix -- operator
but c# doesnot allowed it even that there is different signature's function.
the code:
public static Rational operator --(Rational a)
{
    a.Mona -= a.Mechane;
    return a.reduce();
}
public static Rational operator --(Rational a, int _)
{
    _ = 0;
    Rational original = new Rational(a.Mona, a.Mechane);
    a.Mona -= a.Mechane;
    a.reduce();
    return original;
}


the error:
Overloadable binary operator expected

I tried to do two operators

try to do the same as here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading

@nbk: Which part are you referring to? That page doesn’t show an example of overloading a unary increment/decrement operator.

In C++, it distinguishes prefix and postfix, but in C#, it is only one operator, and you only need to implement the subtract operation.

@Ry- it points to te the same as your overwrite, i upvoted your answer as it is the same as i mentioned in my comment#

The difference between --x and x-- is how the compiler manages the values on the stack in the calling function, not the operator itself.
For the following example;
var a = b + --x + c;
var d = b + x-- + c;

IL equivalent to the following is generated;
stack[0] = b;
stack[1] = x;
stack[1] = --stack[1];
stack[2] = stack[1];
x = stack[2];
stack[0] = stack[0] + stack[1];
stack[1] = c;
stack[0] = stack[0] + stack[1];
a = stack[0];

stack[0] = b;
stack[1] = x;
stack[2] = stack[1];
stack[2] = --stack[2];
x = stack[2];
stack[0] = stack[0] + stack[1];
stack[1] = c;
stack[0] = stack[0] + stack[1];
a = stack[0];

In other words, the variable is loaded, decremented then stored. Either using the built-in operation, or an overloaded one. The difference is if the before value is left on the stack, or the after value is copied instead.

In C#, unary increment/decrement operators are expected to return a new value, not mutate their operand. What you’re trying to do isn’t possible. 12.9.6 Prefix increment and decrement operators in the C# specification:

An operator ++ or operator -- implementation can be invoked using either postfix or prefix notation. It is not possible to have separate operator implementations for the two notations.

Instead, you can implement a named method for operating in place:
public Rational Decrement()
{
    this.Mona -= this.Mechane;
    return this.reduce();
}

and reuse it:
public static Rational operator --(Rational a)
{
    var r = new Rational(a.Mona, a.Mechane);
    r.Decrement();
    return r;
}

There are issues here:

if you do provide operator --, it’s easy to accidentally use an inefficient prefix decrement instead of .Decrement()
the return type of Decrement might lead users to believe it returns a new value instead of being intended for chaining

but if you’re unsatisfied with those tradeoffs, you have to resolve them another way.

In other words, the difference between --x and x-- is how the caller manages the values on the stack, not the operator itself. (see https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANmgExAGoAfAAQCYBGAWAChyBmAAgGcMoBXMDFgNQCGuLjBYBvBi2ksADlGwA3QRjHYAdn2wBuKTOYDhogBQatASkn0ZNlhgAW2NgDpsLALwsde6QF8fLAbk1EiGImIQsjBQKtAscHDGQuEsguYBVrb6AOws6jAA7mEmgq7xLNTmutYy/jXSQSGBKCwAKjAcxpYBNspQLAgeeYXFMMYADFU9Mn2pQwkI1VnSs8BDCAlLtQy+QA=== for an IL example)
